# Why are we attracted to screens?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, eye-movement, visualization, attraction

I'm doing a study about large led billboards and I wanted to understand why we are so attracted to screens and movement in general.

Comment: Hi, welcome at CogSci. Could you provide a little more context to your question? Why are you studying ledboards, and did you do any initial research yourself?

Comment: You can consult numerous material about psychology and consumer behavior of free access on the internet, from this surely you will be able to focus more the question.